# I can't find a comment to my answer

Tags: support, comments, comment-notification

I have posted an answer to this question: [Most dispersed set of points in a disk?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189436/most-dispersed-set-of-points-in-a-disk), but do not see any indication that a comment has been left to that answer, if I however use the StackExchange App, then I see the beginning of some comment "**Comment:** Your first point was not a coarse description, it was perfectly precise. I you edited out (i.e. ..." (end of citation).

Question: where can I find the full comment and, why don't I see any indication, that a comments exists, outside of the StackExchange App?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That comment was deleted by the user, presumably for a legitimate reason. What you're seeing is a remnant of the notification when the comment was posted.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; so the App lets one see more than is ordinarily possible - its a feature, not a bug.

Comment: When the notification was sent, the comment existed.  Deleting (or changing) the comment does not affect the notification.

Comment: Useful to know.  Sometimes I have posted a comment, then soon deleted it when I saw it was nonsense.  But notifications may have been sent anyway!

Comment: Is this really not a bug?  It seems to me that a never-seen notification should disappear if the comment was deleted.

Comment: @EricWofsey: This is not on the main site, so it depends on the app and the type of notification it sends. Some types of notifications have no retraction capabilities (e.g. you can't unsend emails).

Comment: Sometimes (all right, quite often) a comment convinces me that my answer is incorrect, so I delete it, but before I like to answer to the comment acknowledging my mistake. Do I get it right that I can delete me answer straightaway, as the notification will be seen by the person addressed?